# Installation of WiFi Epson SX235W, 4in1 printer / scanner, on Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit?

Tags: installation, wireless, scanner, epson

I got an Epson Stylus SX235W WiFi printer/scanner and ran into some installation problems:

I got the printer working on an USB cable. Trying to go wireless, I need the printers IP address, but the status sheet tells a lot but for the IP address: "none".

Also the scanner I could not install. What do I need and how do I manage, in simple English (step by step) or Dutch?

Answer (score 5):

## Printer

1. For the wifi **printer part** , insert all cratridges (that's quite obvious :P )
2. You have two choiches:

   - You use the Epson disk and setup trough Windows, then you watch in you Access Point or Router the IP the printer received.
   - Or **(preferred)** you can use a router with OTS (or WTS) feature (a button you push to setup a secure network):

     1. press the OTS/WPS button on your wireless router
     2. within 30 seconds press and hold the WiFi button on the Printer until wifi light on the printer will starts flashing
     3. light will turn steady green when connected
     4. check on the router interface (presumably web interface) for the ip assigned to the printer
3. Now in Ubuntu go to Printers, add Printer, Find a Network printer and there should be.

#### NOTE

If you don't find the right driver - or for a better one - you can download  it here:
http://avasys.jp/eng/linux_driver/download/lsb/epson-inkjet/escp/ and install it with: `dpkg -i *.deb`

---

## Scanner

Then for the wifi **scanner part** you have to install some dependencies and iScan

- Download and install dependencies (xsltproc and libltdl7):
  `sudo apt-get install xsltproc libltdl7`
- Go to http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule and search SX235W for Linux.
- Download the "network plugin package" and the "core package&data package". You have to accept the license and then you can download the .deb packages. Be sure to download the right packages (amd64 for 64bit and i386 for 32bit PC). At the end you will have these packages:

  `iscan_VERSION.ltdl7_ARCH.deb
  iscan-data_VERSION_all.deb
  iscan-network-nt_VERSION_ARCH.deb`

  Note that you need iscan for **ltdl7** and NOT ltdl3.
- Install them with  `dpkg -i iscan*.deb`
- If you connect to the scanner by wireless, then to configure Sane as backend, edit: `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` inserting `net (printer_ip)` and then save (where `printer_ip` is the wireless ip of the printer/scanner)
- If you connect to the scanner by usb, then to configure Sane as backend, do:
  `echo 'SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0885", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes", GROUP="scanner"' | sudo tee -a /etc/udev/rules.d/40-scanner.rules`

When at home I can use some screenshots to be clearer if you need.
Best Regards

Comment: Bought this printer printer on ebay for £20 based on this answer and it works brilliantly. I also found the "Installation method" "chapter 4 setting network plug-in" pdf guide useul for configuring the scanner. Epson also has an app for Android Play Store that supports scanning and printing directly from your Android device.

Comment: 2012-10-19: Printer connected by USB was easily recognized by CUPS, very simple and easy, and works great! (did not tried to connect by wireless)

Comment: [This blog post](http://hnygard.no/ubuntu/epson-v300-scanner-on-ubuntu-11-10/) also provides some interesting info although its for a different printer model

Answer (score 0):

I used the drivers from the [Epson website](http://www.epson.co.uk/Store/Printers-and-All-in-Ones/Epson-Stylus-SX525WD/Drivers-Support;jsessionid=2DF10887069CF5DCBED603728C9597BF.acc3-new) for my similar model SX535W

iscan didn't work but with the iscan drivers the KDE "AcquireImages" worked perfectly.

There were 4 packages to install, downloaded them, clicked to install via gdebi.

Check IP address from the printer or your router. You can access a service menu by pointing your browser at the printers IP address. [CUPS auto-discovered my Epson printer](http://alicious.com/epson-install-kubuntu/) for me (link is to details on my blog).